# What are possible reasons a recipient doesn't receive email some of the time, but CC receives it 100% of the time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, office365

We have an internal web application that sends email notifications when a form is submitted.  It sends using an internal exchange server that is connected to Office 365.

The notifications go to a distribution group, and for years this has worked fine, but some weeks ago they started not getting some of the emails, roughly 50% of them.  To try and troubleshoot this issue, I added myself to the CC on the test version of this internal site, and while the distro group still only receives roughly 50% of the notifications they should be receiving, I get 100% of them.  If they submit 10 forms, they'll only receive 5 or so while I receive all 10.

Looking in the exchange trace logs, I can see most of the emails that send successfully to both the distro group and me, but not all of them.  Also mysteriously, I cannot locate the emails that only send to myself at all.

To further complicate this, this all started when some users were errantly added to the distro group, and subsequently removed.  Those users happened to be in a different domain than the others that were already in and still are in the group.

Here is the relevant code that sends the emails upon submission of the form, from a controller action in a .NET Core project.

```
            var mailSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("Mail");
            var clientHost = mailSettings.GetValue<string>("clienthost");
            var clientPort = mailSettings.GetValue<int>("clientport");

            if (account.Status.Equals("Submitted"))
            {
                using (var mail = new MailMessage())
                {
                    
                    string body = "body here";
                    mail.Subject = "subject here";
#if DEBUG
                    mail.Subject = "TEST - " + mail.Subject;
#endif
                    mail.Body = body;
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(account.Email);
                    mail.To.Add("distrogroup@mycompany.fake");
#if DEBUG
                    mail.CC.Add("myemail@mycompany.fake");
#endif
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = clientHost;
                    smtp.Port = clientPort;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }
```

The inconsistent behavior and missing log information is really making me scratch my head, so I'm looking for ideas on what I can do to continue troubleshooting.  What steps would you take to narrow this issue down?  Is there any additional information that I should provide?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

If I replace the distribution group with the individual email addresses that belong to it, they all get them 100% of the time.  I'm really sure what would cause the distro group to fail some of the time, but I thought that was interesting.

Comment: The code is fine, but many e-mail-providers have a very bad spam-detection. To help you, here are few ideas: Maybe some e-mails are moved in the spam-folder. And if the recipients on an other domain  - is the other server rejecting these mails properly?

Comment: Do you send your mails using an account that is able to receive answers? Oftentimes you get a notice when an email is rejected (sometimes with usable hints why it is rejected like dmarc, dkim. etc. policies).

Comment: @akop I looked at someone's screen who was in the distro group and they weren't showing up in their junk folder.  For the second part of your question, I'm not clear; are you saying to try the send with different recipients on a different domain and see if it rejects them?  Thank you.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr I don't think so.  Since I didn't specify credentials, it would just run as the service account for the IIS site, is that correct?  I will try setting it up with a specific set of credentials that receive messages.

Comment: @Mike I was referring to this account `mail.From = new MailAddress(account.Email);`. Use something that is capable of receiving emails and see, if you get rejections answers.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr thanks, I set that field to my own email and didn't get any additional responses when they missed emails with further testing